# How weird of a phrase is "Qué horas son, mi corazón"?

Tags: expresiones, letras-de-canciones

In a lyric from the song "I kissed a girl y me gusta" by Pomplemoose I heard:

> Qué horas son, mi corazón

I'm talking it as semantically equivalent to "qué hora es, mi amor".

It's a cute rhyme for sure, but I'm wondering if "qué horas son" is something you'd actually say?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*¿Qué horas son?* is an alternative for the standard *¿Qué hora es?*. Both mean "What time is it?". The *Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas* says the plural form is "allowed but less advisable" (as reported by [Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/consulta/que-hora-es-o-que-horas-son-200/)) and that it's rather common in some parts of Latin America.

Myself, I use both *¿qué hora es?* and *¿qué horas son?* indifferently. My wife, who I've just queried about the matter, says she used to say *¿qué horas son?* but then started to say it in the singular because the plural version sounded "uneducated", but cannot tell how exactly she got that idea into her head. (Actually she still says *¿qué horas son?* sometimes.)

The plural question is also used exclusively in idiomatic expressions indicating disapproval, typically like this:

> *¿Qué horas son éstas de llegar?*

or moving things around a bit,

> *¿Qué horas de llegar son éstas?*

The literal meaning of this is "What times for coming home are these?", but the intended meaning is more or less "Do you think you can come home so late!?".

I think the song you're quoting is actually by Manu Chao and it's called *[Me gustas tú](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RqDE20auDH8)*.

Comment: ¡Agradezco a ti y tu esposa! Pomplomoose is a cover band (and a great one!), thanks for pointing me to the original.

Comment: Es muy interesante el uso de la lengua que hace Manu Chao: es francés de padres (exiliados) españoles, ha vivido en bastantes lugares (actualmente en Barcelona) y tanto su música como sus músicos tienen enlaces con múltiples lugares. Incluso su banda en algún momento tiene una resonancia interesante: se llamaba _Radio Bemba_, que recuerdo haber oído a Manu explicar que venía de una canción de ¿Ricardo Arjona? Pues se refiere al _rumor que va de boca en boca_ ([fuente](https://www.lavozdegalicia.es/noticia/cultura/2007/08/03/dicho-pues-radio-bemba/00032B1EF479D4A6BC8401B664BB63C9F5BD.htm)).

Comment: @fedorqui Manu Chao fue *all the rage* en cierta época en Argentina (supongo que en toda LatAm) y *Me gustas tú* especialmente, así que no podía menos que recordar esa letra.

Comment: Aquí en España también fue un verdadero éxito, sonaba por todo. Yo me quedo con el anterior, _Clandestino_. Si algún día llega a tus manos, recomiendo leer _Mano Negra en Colombia: un tren de hielo y fuego_ sobre el viaje en tren que hizo Mano Negra junto a otros artistas a principios de los años 90. Lo escribió Ramón Chao, padre de Manu.

Comment: Yo añadiría que también puede ser una importación del portugués "Que horas são?"

Comment: @DiegoSánchez Me pasó por la cabeza eso pero no tenía manera de comprobarlo.